# Sonarqube Elasticsearch Error - low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running Sonarqube in Docker which uses Elasticsearch and I am running into the low disk watermark error. I do know what the error means and at this time, it is not feasible to free up disk space and want to disable the threshold (or raise limits).

I attempted to mount the elasticsearch.yml configuration file with the following settings which don't seem to apply:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 95%
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 98%
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage: 99%
```

```
property@hercules:/tmp/sonarqube$ docker-compose logs -f
Attaching to sonarqube
...
sonarqube    | 2019.08.27 14:31:00 INFO  es[][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [EjQrrQMsTOKVujBLRdH89Q][sonarqube][/opt/sonarqube/data/es6/nodes/0] free: 96.5gb[10.9%], replicas will not be assigned to this node

user@server:/tmp/sonarqube$ docker-compose exec sonarqube bash
sonarqube@bf4144c9bba6:/opt/sonarqube$ cat elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml | grep cluster\.routing
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 95%
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 98%
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage: 99%
```

It doesn't seem like the setting is taking effect. I actually doubt that the configuration file is even being consumed. Sonarqube doesn't seem to provide any documentation on configuring Elasticsearch.

Sonarqube does document the error but says just free up space - https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/troubleshooting/ (under Recovering from Elasticsearch read-only indices).

Any ideas on how I can ensure that `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false` is used?

Comment: I went into the container and ran a docker ps which showed me that the configuration path used is /opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es however looking at the elasticsearch.yml file, it warns not to change as it is generated on startup. When I mount one of the files or entire folder, I get access denied exceptions as it looks like it tries to create the folder and then files.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. [Here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/138171d657c57fe015c4dcc4be996973f87f5365/server/sonar-main/src/main/java/org/sonar/application/es/EsYmlSettings.java) and [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/abb1aca918803d7e4d25e7a493ead5db05abaa6e/server/sonar-main/src/main/java/org/sonar/application/command/CommandFactoryImpl.java) (line 145) you can find the related source code to start some more research.

Comment: There is a similar question here and you can find my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227388

let me know if your problem does not resolve.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, thanks for pointing me to the source. I probably won't continue this effort. Was able to free up enough space for now. Will try to find somewhere else to put it long term.

Comment: @hamidbayat, appreciate the guidance. I was able to free up space for now but will try the curl request to apply the setting. While I prefer to store this config in a file, it is okay as it would just be used to workaround my disk space issue and won't be deployed to prod like this.